# routing rtmp ect streams

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, routing, streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to solve this problem using ffmpeg+pyhton or in conjunction with another solution.
I need a server solution, so Vmix, obs, etc are not suitable. (
eg: I have two (and/or more) streams

```
rtmp://host/live/input_stream_1
rtmp://host address/live/input_stream_2
 ect
```

Is it possible to organize "routing" of streams (choosing a priority live-video-stream and applying layers to them according to the logic:

There is `input_stream_1` - it is default and local - videos from a network folder are packed via ffmpeg and fly to `rtmp://host address/live/output_stream_1A` (+ overlay layers -ect logos).

It is necessary, when an incoming stream `input_stream_2` appears, to replace the content of `input_stream_1` with the content of `input_stream_2` and send it, and when `input_stream_2` stops, going to return `input_stream_1` ?

Maybe it will be a combination of ffmpeg (as suggested in [this thread](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33984/combine-mp4-video-and-a-rtmp-stream-into-1-rtmp-output-stream-via-ffmpeg) and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278415/how-to-sync-multiple-rtsp-inputs-in-ffmpeg)) and [python solutions](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

The logic of the layers might be like: [PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U42Ms.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
```

## Set the input and output streams

input_stream_1 = "rtmp://host/live/input_stream_1"
input_stream_2 = "rtmp://host/live/input_stream_2"
output_stream = "rtmp://host/live/output_stream"

## Set the default input stream

current_input_stream = input_stream_1

## Set the overlay layers to apply to the stream

overlay_layers = "-i logo.png -filter_complex overlay"

## Use a while loop to continuously read and route the streams

while True:
# Use FFmpeg to read the current input stream and write the output stream
ffmpeg_command = f"ffmpeg -i {current_input_stream} {overlay_layers} -c copy {output_stream}"
subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, shell=True)

```
# Check for incoming streams and switch to them if necessary
if incoming_stream_2_is_active():
    current_input_stream = input_stream_2
else:
    current_input_stream = input_stream_1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).